# Cannot specify 4 arguments (hash algorithm name) for Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

According to the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_Rfc2898DeriveBytes__ctor_System_Byte___System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithmName_), I should be able to create `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with a custom hash algorithm (SHA256 in my case):

```
public Rfc2898DeriveBytes (byte[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations, System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm);
```

I have created a .NET Standard 2.0 class library with the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

My Class

```
private static byte[] Pbkdf2(string data)
{
    // ...
    using(var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(null, null, 50000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256))
    {
        return pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> 'Rfc2898DeriveBytes' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments

Why can I not add a hash algorithm to the constructor of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`?

Comment: For what it's worth this API with HashAlgorithmName will be part of .NET Standard 2.1. https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes..ctor(String,Int32,Int32,HashAlgorithmName)

Comment: I'm unable to use .NET Standard 2.1 as I need the library to be shared between .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET Core. Any advice? 3rd Party Library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you posted is for .NET Framework, not .NET Standard. The documentation for.NET Standard [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.-ctor?view=netstandard-2.0#System_Security_Cryptography_Rfc2898DeriveBytes__ctor_System_Byte___System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithmName_). In .NET Standard there is no constructor with 4 parameters.

Comment: Wow, I guess I missed that little version switcher select list at the top. Thanks!